# There is a point in using some virtualization technology just to one host?

Tags: virtualization

Quick and dirty: there's a point to virtualise a server in a single host? Using an hypervisor.

It would be better to just install the OS in bare metal or some features like the remote software KVM through a browser or software from the hypervisor, image management and some fancy extras will compensate the performance hit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Updates are faster (less downtime) and less dangerous if you can do them with a copy of the VM while the VM is running.

You can have a very simple host configuration (fast updates here, too). All configuration complexity is in the VM. So if you have to change the bare metal this is easier.

You can easily put a second VM on the same host if that later turns out to be useful. Without the initial VM you would need a VM configuration in your application system where it doesn't belong.

It's much less probable that the simple host (with hardly any changes to the OS) has a crash with boot problems. A crashed VM can be managed via virtual serial console (without fancy hardware or additional systems).

Answer (score 1):

The performance hit isn't usually as big as you'd imagine (in the order of 3-4%) but, if i've understood your question correctly then yes, it's usually worth it. You gain the ability to move it elsewhere easily, snapshotting, and as you say, remote KVM.

Answer (score 0):

It depends...

For Windows, I rarely see the need for bare-metal OS installations. Especially as modern systems tend to have more resources available than a typical Windows OS can take advantage of.

For Linux, there are situations where I know I can leverage all of the physical server's resources (or get granular with cgroups, taskset, CPU pinning, etc.), so I will install bare-metal.

The portability aspect doesn't factor in much. I also think that native OS management tools are more developed than their hypervisor variants on enterprise-class server hardware... HP's management agents and Dell's utilities come to mind.